# How can i apply extra fees for selected products

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, sku

I need to apply some percentage off fees for selected products, how can I do that?

Comment: is there any problem for using custom option ?

Comment: I dont know completely, how can i apply?

Comment: Is any possible methods exist?